# Oracle table fragmentation

Tags: oracle, fragmentation

How do I fragment a table so that it is distributed over multiple oracle 9i servers.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle horizontal scability feature is called [RAC (Real Application Clusters)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/intro.htm#sthref148). It allows a cluster of servers to act as a single database. It is a share-everything architecture: all servers have access to the full database that resides on shared disks.

In other words, you wouldn't "fragment" a table accross multiple servers in Oracle. You can look into [partitioning](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/intro.htm#sthref201), which allows you to partition a table accross several tablespaces.

Partitioning is an [Entreprise Edition](http://www.oracle.com/database/product_editions.html) feature, RAC is an option of the Entreprise Edition.

Comment: Technically, it's a shared-disk architecture (there's one copy of the data), not a shared-everything database (each server can have its own copy of the oracle binaries, each instance of the database writes its own redo log files and maintains its own undo, but the other instances do need access to them).

Comment: @adam: absolutely, although I used the "shared everything" term in opposition to the "shared nothing" architecture (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_nothing_architecture) more common in other RDBMSes

Comment: You can have Standard Edition RAC, but the total number of CPUs is limited to 4. With that limitation it is more of a Availability solution than a scalability one.